# Two select statement in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called Teacher it have the detail of all the teachers it have fields like first_name,last_name,email,phone_number 
I want to get the count as well as all the detail of the teacher so I wrote a query like this

```
SELECT
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
         FROM Teacher 
        WHERE is_disabled = false
     ) total_count
     , id
     , Teacher.*
  FROM Teacher 
 WHERE is_disabled = 0;
```

It gives the correct output but when I try to add limit and offset the count gets changed like

```
SELECT
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
        FROM Teacher 
       WHERE is_disabled = false
     ) as total_count
     , Teacher.*
  FROM Teacher 
 WHERE is_disabled = 0 
 LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 10;
```

So if i have 9 teacher in my database it will not show me any result but I want to get the total count as 9 every time even if there are not any teacher for some limit and offset

Comment: Sample data would be really helpful here.

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine what your output would look like if you don't have any teacher details returned or what sense it would make.

Comment: I just want the total count even if there are no teacher for a certain limit and offset It will really help me in my pagination just let me know if it is possible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT
     t.firstname, t.lastname, t.phonenumber, t.emailaddress, 0 is_count, 0 total_count
  FROM Teacher T
 WHERE is_disabled = 0 
 LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 10
UNION
SELECT
     '','','','', 1, ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
        FROM Teacher 
       WHERE is_disabled = false
     )
;
```

This will give you an extra record with the count that you'll have to filter from your list in your GUI (the one where is_count=1).  Honestly though, I think you should look at using 2 different result sets instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the limit and offset to the subquery:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
        FROM Teacher 
        WHERE is_disabled = 0
        LIMIT 10  OFFSET 10
       ) as total_count,
       t.*
FROM Teacher t
WHERE t.is_disabled = 0 
LIMIT 10  OFFSET 10;
```

Or alternatively, use a variable:

```
SELECT t.*, @rn as total_count
FROM (SELECT t.*, @rn := @rn + 1)
      FROM Teacher t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
      WHERE t.is_disabled = 0 
      LIMIT 10  OFFSET 10
     ) t;
```